# How do I make multiple event bindings with ImpromptuInterface.MVVM?

Tags: wpf, impromptu-interface

Binding to a single event with ImpromptuInterface.MVVM is very simple:

```
<DataGrid MVVM:Event.Bind="{Binding Events.RowEditEnding.To[DoRowEditEnding]}"
 ...
```

How do I bind to a second event in the same DataGrid control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always chain another event after the `To` statement. Here is an example where I've used it to bind multiple mouse listening events from one object:

```
  <Grid Background="{Binding Color}" MVVM:Event.Bind="{Binding Events.MouseEnter.To[CenterMouseEnter].MouseLeave.To[MouseLeave].MouseLeftButtonDown.To[LeftButtonClick]}"
```